# chkdsk errors in Windows XP SP2 — how do I repair the file system?

Tags: windows-xp, filesystems, filesystem-corruption

I have problems booting my Windows XP SP2 in any mode.

So, I ran the installation CD in the repair mode and entered the repair console. There, I ran the chkdsk command and found errors on my C drive.

I tried running `chkdsk /f` to fix the errors, but in vain. The command prompt says that only `/p` and `/r` options are applicable.

Now, what do I do to repair the file system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chkdsk /r is probably your best choice, it checks everything and tries to repair bad blocks.  To be honest though you're probably going to need a new hard drive but there's no harm in trying.

Answer (score 0):

Do exactly what you did but change the command to `chkdsk c:\ /r` which will try to repair the bad sectors.